# Arithmetic dataframe and a vector

Tags: r, dataframe

If I have a dataframe, say iris, and I want to subtract a vector with same column names how can I do this?

```
df <- structure(list(Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5, 5.4), 
    Sepal.Width = c(3.5, 3, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9), Petal.Length = c(1.4, 
    1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7), Petal.Width = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
    0.2, 0.2, 0.4)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

vec <- tibble(Sepal.Length = 1, Sepal.Width = 2, Petal.Length = 3, Petal.Width = 4)
```

And I want to do something like this `df - vec`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be to `unlist` the 'vec'.  Here 'vec' is a `tibble` with one row.  One way is to replicate the 'vec' to make the lengths equal by using `col` which gives the column indexes.  With that index, the dataset is replicated. Once the dimension is similar, we can do the subtraction

```
df - unlist(vec)[col(df)]
```

---

Or using `uncount`, the `tibble` rows are replicated to get the same dimension as 'df'

```
df - vec %>% 
          uncount(nrow(df))
```

Comment: Please explain why should I do unlist here?

Comment: @SteveS. You created a `tibble` instead of a `vector` and tibble doesn't allow for replicating with `col`.  So, I `unlist`.  Can be done in many ways though

Comment: Dear akrun, can you please share some other ways to do this also?

Comment: And please explain what does it mean tibble doesn't allow for replicating with col

Comment: can you please explain? @akrun

Comment: But the dimensions are the same, 4 columns in each tibble, not the same amount of rows.

Comment: @SteveS Yes, the number of rows are not the same, With data.frame, there is recycling, here it is not doing that

Comment: I see, and there is no way to recycle in tibble? 
Still can't understand how col replicates the vector.

Comment: @SteveS If you check the `col(df)`, it gives the index for each column replicated with the number of rows and return as a matrix.  so, for each 1, the first element of vec will be selected, similarly for each 2, 2nd element and so on.  It is similar to `c(4, 2)[c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)]`

Answer (score 2):

Or:

```
map_dfc(seq_along(colnames(df)), ~df[[.x]] - vec[[.x]])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do

```
df - vec
```

It returns

> Error in Ops.data.frame(df, vec) : 
>     ‘-’ only defined for equally-sized data frames

So one way is to make equal sized dataframe and subtract

```
df - vec[rep(nrow(vec), each = nrow(df)), names(df)]

#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#1          4.1         1.5         -1.6        -3.8
#2          3.9         1.0         -1.6        -3.8
#3          3.7         1.2         -1.7        -3.8
#4          3.6         1.1         -1.5        -3.8
#5          4.0         1.6         -1.6        -3.8
#6          4.4         1.9         -1.3        -3.6
```